# Which AMP extensions can fetch a response from an endpoint?

Tags: cross-domain, amp-html

What [AMP extensions](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/extensions) can be used to get a response from the server in the form of variable that can be used later, such as in a [template](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-mustache/amp-mustache.md) or as a [parameter to an attribute](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5811#issuecomment-256433144)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### amp-access

The [authorization endpoint](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#authorization-endpoint) of [amp-access](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access) can return ["a free-form JSON object"](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access#access-content-markup_1):

> Here’s a small list of possible ideas for properties that can be returned from the Authorization endpoint:
>
> - Metering info: maximum allowed number of views and current number of views.
> - Whether the Reader is logged in or a subscriber.
> - A more detailed type of the subscription: basic, premium
> - Geo: country, region, custom publication region

### amp-form

[amp-form](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#successerror-response-rendering) "allows publishers to render the responses using [Extended Templates](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#extended-templates)". The response is expected to be a valid JSON Object. Try the "Hiding input fields after success" demo in the [amp-form sample](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/) to see it in action.

[image: amp-form submission with page update]

### amp-list

[amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) fetches "content dynamically from a CORS JSON endpoint and renders it using a supplied template". The response must be a JSON object that contains an array property "items".

In addition to `{{variable}}` substitutions in Mustache templates, you can also use [`AUTHDATA(variable)`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-access/amp-access-analytics.md#authdatafield) elsewhere.

### amp-live-list (not quite)

[amp-live-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-live-list) is a "wrapper and minimal UI for content that updates live in the client instance as new content is available in the source document". The page will re-fetch itself, giving the server a change to send new content. If new content is found, AMP will populate a `<div items>` element with the new (HTML) [items](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-live-list#items). You can't use that as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's name doesn't really suggest it, but I think you want `AMP-list`

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-list/amp-list.md

> Fetches content dynamically from a CORS JSON endpoint and renders it using a supplied template.